# Update a value of previous given integer (Python) Beginner

Tags: python-3.x

Still in my infancy of learning Python, and here's what I'm trying to do.

It's a simple ATM program that takes an account number, gives a starting balance ($1000), and offers basic ATM functions (Deposit, withdraw, or exit).

What I can't figure out is how to update the "currentbalance" to reflect the transaction the user has taken, and then keep that value in case the user wants to make another transaction.

So, every time the user goes through, and (for example) deposits $100, it'll give the "currentbalance" of $1100.  But if the user does another transaction, it'll use the starting balance of $1000 for subsequent transactions.

I'm not looking for a "gimme" answer, if you can point me in the right direction I'll appreciate it a ton.  I've gotten this far by working on my own, but this one I just can't figure out.  And I want to understand this stuff, not just get the answer (although I'm getting so frustrated I won't say no to the answer!!).

```
def beginning():
    print ("Please enter your account number *NOTE: Please use 12345 for the excercise")
    account = int(input("Account number: "))

    while True:
        if account != 12345:
            print ("Please check your account number and try again")
            beginning()
        else: account == 12345
        break

beginning()

startbalance = int(1000)

print("Your current balance is $ ",int(startbalance))

def transaction():

    startbalance = int(1000)

    trans = input("What type of transaction do you want to do\n\
press 'W' for Withdrawl; 'D' for deposit; or 'E' to Exit:  ")

    if (trans == "D") or (trans == "d"):
        deposit = input("Enter amount to deposit: ")
        deposit = int(deposit)

        currentbalance = deposit + startbalance
        print ("Current Balance: $", int(currentbalance))
        transaction()

    if (trans == "W") or (trans == "w"):
        withdraw = input("Enter amount to withdraw: ")
        withdraw = int(withdraw)

        if withdraw > startbalance:
            print ("Insufficient funds, please start over")
            transaction()
        if withdraw <= startbalance:
            currentbalance = startbalance - withdraw
            print ("Current Balance: $", int(currentbalance))
            transaction()

    if (trans == "E") or (trans == "e"):
        endofprogram = input("Please hit enter to exit from this program")

transaction()
```

Comment: You could implement classes to do that.  The attributes of the Account class variable is the current balance and the methods are operations the user can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with scoping. `currentbalance` is declared and updated within the `if` code block for deposits, which has its own scoping, similar to C, C++, and many many other languages. If you'd like `currentbalance` to keep a running record of the current balance in an account, you'll need to declare it at a higher scope, for example, in this case it would need to be at global scope, which introduces other issues. A better solution would be to pass `currentbalance` as a parameter to `transaction()`, but it's your choice . As it is now, `currentbalance` is deleted as soon as your program leaves the scope of the `if`, and is recreated as a blank variable each time you enter the `if`.

Additionally, your withdrawal code has a few issues dealing with `currentbalance`, but I'm sure you'll be able to fix those on your own :)

Comment: THANK YOU! I think I have it now.  And, yeah, I figured out the withdrawl code right when I read back through it, stupid mistake!

Comment: No problem. We all started somewhere. Stuff like this will be second nature to you someday, but it takes time and practice. If my answer helped you out, please consider accepting it as correct. :)